# Setting Results Set of MySQL Column as Column Value

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL have a column containing house prices, with the house prices reported in cents instead of dollars. I would like to update the column values to their dollar value but haven't been able to figure out how to do so. I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO tiny_house_listings(price) 
VALUES(SELECT (default_price/100) FROM tiny_house_listings);
```

and

```
UPDATE tiny_house_listings 
SET price = (SELECT (default_price/100) FROM tiny_house_listings);
```

How does one typically go about accessing results sets returned in previous queries? Are they typically added as columns are is one able to access them via their aliased name? Would really appreciate any guidance on the subject!:)

Comment: 'How does one typically go about accessing results sets returned in previous queries' - one doesn't. And neither of your queries is correct - you cannot mix values and select in this way in an insert and an update statement updates on a row by row basis (you also don't have a where so a corrected version of the update would update all rows) Also after the first iteration you won't be able to tell which rows are now expressed in dollars and which are in cents.

Comment: @Strawberry my question clearly says that I haven't been able to figure out how to do what I'm asking...That's why I'm asking the question. > " I would like to update the column values to their dollar value but haven't been able to figure out how to do so."

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you, that's the answer I was looking for! And I ultimately used the following: ````UPDATE tiny_house_listings 
SET price = (default_price/100)```` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just this :

```
UPDATE tiny_house_listings 
SET price = default_price/100;
```

Can you show us your table definition ?